# How is Composer giving me warning updates needed for packages not in my composer file?

Tags: laravel, homestead

When I update Composer I'm getting warnings that certain packages are out of date and should be removed or replaced, as normal. However, many of these packages do not exist in the composer file. I've even tried clearing the composer cache and rebuilding my server (Homestead).

So I did a directory search and discovered there are files that exist in the Vendor directory. But I don't know how they got there.

Can anyone explain? I assume I can just delete them from there and these warnings will go away, but I'm not certain and I'm more concerned about how they got there.

Comment: Probably they're are dependencies of other packages .... you can navegate to any folder in your vendor, and you will see another composer.json ... inside that file, you'll see other dependencies

Comment: Thank you, that's a great idea I will investigate and report back here what I find if it seems helpful to others curious about this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `composer depends packagename` to find out which package(s) in your composer.json they're dependencies of.  You may need to update some of them if the newer versions have removed the dependent packages producing the errors.

Just deleting them from the vendor folder will probably end up causing problems.